# Can't get my php form working (cant send the email)

Tags: php, contacts, contact-form

To being with, Im really bad with PHP, not my area. Sorry for any stupid stuff I might say

EDIT: I tried echoing the vars as you guys sayd to, and comes out I cant get any value out of it.

EDIT2: Those "class required" works for my jquery validation script. You guys think i should post it too?

Well, im facing a php contact form problem. I dont know much about php too, so this make stuff harder.

Well, I've tried mailtest.php to check if it was my hosting, but it is working ok. So here is the code:

```
<form class="validate" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

    <span class="fill">Todos os campos são obrigatórios.</span>
    <span><label>Nome:</label><input name="nome" type="text" class="required" /></span><br />
    <span><label>E-mail:</label><input name="mail" type="text" class="required email" /></span><br />
    <span><label>Empresa:</label><input name="empresa" type="text" class="required" /></span><br />
    <span><label>Telefone:</label><input style="width: 150px;" name="phone" type="text" class="required" /></span><br />                   
    <span><label>Mensagem:</label><textarea name="mensagem" cols="38" rows="8" class="required"></textarea></span><br />
    <span><input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" /></span>

</form>
```

And here it is my php coding:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "fernando_fleury@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Contato Website - Nicotec";
$name = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['mensagem'];

$body = "De: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email\n Empresa: $empresa\n Telefone: $phone\n Mensagem:\n $message";

mail($to, $subject, $body);
}

header('Location: contato.html');

?>
```

It is possible to check it live too on: http://www.fernandofleury.com.br/preview/nicotec/contato.html

What am i doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the mail not sent? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @Charles With the header in place, he won't see any error messages. Anything that is shown will be vanished by the header redirect.

Comment: I just removed the header to check for error messages, got none actually.

Comment: Putting `print_r($_POST)` at top(after `<?php` could help a lot..

Comment: Davinder, I get an error message from adding the print_r($_POST) on my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` check to make sure that all of your required fields are set along the lines of `if(isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['mail']) && isset($_POST['phone']) ....`

Then if that fails, echo out the `$to`, `$subject` and `$body`. Comment out the `header` to see the results while you test it.

Also, try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $to = "fernando_fleury@hotmail.com";
    $subject = "Contato Website - Nicotec";
    $name = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['mensagem'];

    $body = "De: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email\n Empresa: $empresa\n Telefone: $phone\n Mensagem:\n $message";

    mail($to, $subject, $body);

    header('Location: contato.html');
}
else
{
    echo "Ruh ohes! Something wasn't set!";
}
```

edit: to echo out a var to the screen use (in the example of `$to` this code:

```
echo $to;
```

Edit 2:

I had a look at your page and you use javascript to ensure that all the fields are filled in. Therefore, the problem almost certainly lies in this line:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Can you change it to:

```
if(!empty($_POST['nome']) && !empty($_POST['mail']) && !empty($_POST['empresa']) && !empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['mensagem']))
```

for me please? Perhaps the `$_POST['Submit']` isn't being sent properly.

Comment: EDIT: Fluffeh, thanks for your info about it. I added your code and echoed the error message, so something is really running wrong there. I just can get where it is wrong. Is there any wrong semanthic?

Comment: Well, I just added it along with the echo again. But the echo is not triggering, so I suppose im not getting any errors now? But the form is still not working. You think maybe the jquery validation could be screwing it up?

EDIT: I removed the validator and still not working. Should I look for another email sender? This one i kinda "built" myself.

Comment: @fernandofleury If the echo is not triggering (which means it is, but is displaying nothing unless you have it within an if statement) it means that the `$_POST` for that value is not being sent. Don't use it inside the `if(...)` statement. Check the other fields as I suggest - they are the ones that matter anyhow.

Comment: Should i just remove the if statement then?

Comment: @fernandofleury You seem to do a pretty good job of validating the results in javascript before you post. I would consider removing the `if(...)` statement acceptable until you pick through your code with a fine tooth comb, yes.

Comment: Fluffeh, I've just got the email on my inbox. With a huge delay, but it was sent anyway. I will try sending a few others to check the gap time. Thanks a lot for your effort on it.

Comment: @fernandofleury No worries, this is what SO does. Feel free to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is unclear. "It doesn't work" is a very broad explanation :) So in order to get proper help, describe the following:

- what action do you take?
- what result do you get?
- what was the expected result?

Also: try to chop the process into pieces:

- does the mail work ok?
- is it only the redirect?
- is it both?
- etc...

Not a solution, but a debug tip:
Try:

```
 print_r($_POST);
```

And see what the result is. It might tell you more.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear about it, I will try to explain it further:

The email doesnt send at all, although the last header function works and redirect me back to page.

I tried to remove the header function to get error message or anything like, but no error messages too. I would like to know what Im doing wrong.

Comment: @fernandofleury Your process exists of at least 3 parts: 1) posting+receiving form data, 2) constructing+sending email, 3) redirecting. I suggest you first get those separate phase right. And then you connect them. E.g. phase 2): create a new file in which you don't read any POST data, but you only try to send a mail to yourself. Just hardcode the title, body, empresa, etc... and then say `if( mail(...) ){ echo 'did send, now check your mailbox'; }else{ echo 'something went wrong sending'; };`.

Answer (score 1):

You should also add the following to the top of your php file while you are testing to see errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

And add inside all of your inputs:

```
value=""
```

which sends an empty string by default.
To view what is coming out just add to your send_form_email.php

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

because you don't need to write if(isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['mail']) etc.  Sometimes the submit input name is changed by PHP, so you can find the right name using var_dump.